# Create a Random Color to highlight text on in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, random

Hello I am trying to create a function in vb.net to create a randomly generated color to highlight rows in a ListView on a form. The input to the code is SlaveID which is a Byte. The problem I am having is that if I input the Same SlaveID in multiple times, I will always get the same color output. Since Rnd takes in current time to make the number more random, the colour output changes every time I call this function even though my input value stays the same. Is there a random number generator that is not effected by time that would be an easy replacement for Rnd?

```
Private Function GetColourForRow(ByVal SlaveID As Byte)
    Dim ListViewItemColour As New ListViewItem        
    Dim upperbound As Byte = 255
    Dim lowerbound As Byte = 100
    Dim ColourA As Int16 = CInt(Math.Floor((upperbound * 2 - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd(SlaveID) + 2)) + lowerbound
    Dim ColourR As Int16 = CInt(Math.Floor((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd(SlaveID))) + lowerbound
    Dim ColourG As Int16 = CInt(Math.Floor((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd(SlaveID + 5))) + lowerbound
    Dim ColourB As Int16 = CInt(Math.Floor((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd(SlaveID + 15))) + lowerbound        

Return ListViewItemColour.BackColor
```

End Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Visual Basic .NET and not old Visual Basic, I suggest you make use of the [Random class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) of the Framework. Let's use OOP since it exists...

So that would give you

```
Public Class MyClass
  'We will instanciate the Random number generator using a seed
  Private _seed As Integer = CInt(Date.Now.Ticks And &h0000FFFF)

  Private Function GetColourForRow(ByVal SlaveID As Byte)
    Dim Random As New Random(_seed)

    'These numbers will always be the same, because the seed will not change...
    Dim number1 = Random.Next(minimum, maximum)
    Dim number2 = Random.Next(minimum, maximum)

    'Rest of your function
  End Function

  'Rest of your class
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

To generate the same pseudo random numbers each time, you can [`Randomize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tdhk2yh) with the same seed:

```
 Private Function GetColourForRow(ByVal SlaveID As Byte)
    Static seed# = Rnd() ' Static values will be set only the first time the function is called and will stay the same
    Randomize(seed)
    ' the rest of the code
```

Answer (score 1):

Before using `Rnd`, you can call `Randomize(x)` with a consistent value of `x` to seed the random number generator with something other than the current time. You'll likely want to do this at the top of `GetColourForRow`.

For more information, see:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zedbtdt(v=vs.90).aspx

However, this may have unintentional side effects if you use random numbers elsewhere in your program. It may be more appropriate to use a hash function such as MD5 or SHA to map the SlaveID consistently to some random-looking bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I wrote using @Slai answer

```
Private Function GetColourForRow(ByVal MessageID As Byte)
    Dim ListViewItemColour As New ListViewItem
    'MessageID = MessageID + (ListViewPosition / 2)
    Dim ModValue As Byte = MessageID Mod 8

    Dim upperbound As Byte = 255
    Dim lowerbound As Byte = 100

    Dim RandomA As New Random(MessageID * 100000)
    Dim RandomR As New Random((MessageID + 10) * 5000)
    Dim RandomG As New Random((MessageID + 5) * 80000)
    Dim RandomB As New Random((MessageID + 15) * 90000)




    'upperbound is multiplied by two since it is brightness. needs to be larger
    Dim ColourA As Int16 = CInt(Math.Floor((upperbound * 2 - lowerbound + 1) * RandomA.NextDouble) + lowerbound)
    Dim ColourR As Int16 = CInt(Math.Floor((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * RandomR.NextDouble) + lowerbound)
    Dim ColourG As Int16 = CInt(Math.Floor((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * RandomG.NextDouble) + lowerbound)
    Dim ColourB As Int16 = CInt(Math.Floor((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * RandomB.NextDouble) + lowerbound)

    If ColourA > 255 Or ColourA < 0 Then ColourA = 255
    If ColourR > 255 Or ColourR < 0 Then ColourR = 255
    If ColourB > 255 Or ColourB < 0 Then ColourB = 255
    If ColourG > 255 Or ColourG < 0 Then ColourG = 255


    ListViewItemColour.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(ColourA, ColourR, ColourB, ColourG)
    Return ListViewItemColour.BackColor
```

End Function